# How to Enable Hamburger Menu for Tablet/Ipad using Shopify | Debut Theme 2020

Tags: media-queries, themes, shopify, responsive, hamburger-menu

I've been searching for a way to enable the debut theme Hamburger menu on Ipad or tablet. Everything works with mobile, but I want to be able to see the hamburger menu on tablet and Ipad as well. Hope someone can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Debut 2020 Version

Copy all the code of your **Assets -> theme.css.liquid** fine and paste it in any Editor (i.e. Sublime)

Find `max-width: 749px` and replace all the instance with `max-width: 768px`

**Also replace:**

`min-width: 750px` with `min-width: 769px`

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

To show the hamburger menu on tablet and Ipad,

**This solution is for old (2019) Debut Version in which @mixin are used**

Find
`$grid-breakpoints:`
in your Assets -> theme.scss file.

It will look like this:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  $small '(max-width: #{$grid-medium - 1})',
  $medium '(min-width: #{$grid-medium}) and (max-width: #{$grid-large - 1})',
  $medium-down '(max-width: #{$grid-large - 1})',
  $medium-up '(min-width: #{$grid-medium})',
  $large '(min-width: #{$grid-large}) and (max-width: #{$grid-widescreen - 1})',
  $large-down '(max-width: #{$grid-widescreen - 1})',
  $large-up '(min-width: #{$grid-large})',
  $widescreen '(min-width: #{$grid-widescreen})'
);
```

And replace it with the following code:

```
$custom-grid-medium: 769px;
$grid-breakpoints: (
  $small '(max-width: #{$custom-grid-medium - 1})',
  $medium '(min-width: #{$grid-medium}) and (max-width: #{$grid-large - 1})',
  $medium-down '(max-width: #{$grid-large - 1})',
  $medium-up '(min-width: #{$grid-medium})',
  $large '(min-width: #{$grid-large}) and (max-width: #{$grid-widescreen - 1})',
  $large-down '(max-width: #{$grid-widescreen - 1})',
  $large-up '(min-width: #{$grid-large})',
  $widescreen '(min-width: #{$grid-widescreen})'
);
```

In this code i replace the first variable "$grid-medium" with new variable called "$custom-grid-medium".

**Note: After implementation you need to adjust some areas of your theme according.**

Comment: Thank you for responding, But I can't seem to find the exact code in the new 2020 Debut theme. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Vonskie sorry i had the older version of debut theme. For Debut 2020 i have added a new solution for you. Try it. Thanks

Comment: It works. thank you so much for your help, I had to change some css code for the layout but just a little.

Comment: Yeah you need to change some CSS to adjust the layout. Good to hear its works for you.